# my =Importrange Formula on Google sheet doesn't work with multiple Xlookups in the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, xlookup

I'm making a budget sheet on google sheets. When I use importrange on my google sheet, it works perfectly fine. However when I use an Xlookup in a different tab and different cell, the Importrange fails and gets stuck on loading. I'm not sure why... It may be because they loosely reference each other? I'm using Xlookups to sum a range which includes some of the imported data... But in my mind, that shouldn't affect the Importrange at all. If you delete all the xlookups, the importrange pushes through, and if there is only 1 Xlookup in the entire sheet, Importrange still works... Can anyone help??? I've linked the sheet below so that you can play with it. You can change the links for the importrange freely.

FYI you have to delete the importrange / refresh the page after each change as the importrange will just keep the data their until there is a change on either the data side or sheet side.

[Link to the Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RAMZrveRBoHxNZKT-g5cmAuiMidN1QRR7_6bRijOIDo/edit#gid=1124412291)

I tried deleting all Xlookups and and changing the Importange Range to lessen the impact
I tried array constraining other formulas in the sheet because I thought it was stuck on too many calculations
I tried simplifying the Xlookup formulas to set ranges.

Answer (score 0):

you can build your `IMPORTRANGE` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(NOW()/0)&IMPORTRANGE(D2; "A1:A4"))
```

and with:

[image]

changes won't be instant of course but they will flow more often

Comment: I tried it, but I just get an error message saying that: "this function is not allowed to reference a cell with NOW(), RAND(), or RANDBETWEEN()"

Comment: No good either :(

Comment: @J-QUAN updated, try with AF

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work either, I'm starting to think it has more to do with xlookup than it does importrange

Answer (score 0):

If you could use `VLOOKUP()` instead of `XLOOKUP()` in the source Googlesheet, the `IMPORTRANGE()` should work.